# Cannot access offset of type string on string after Upgrading to PHP 8.0

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I keep getting the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in...

on this line:

`<a class="menu-item__second-level" href="<?php echo $second_level_link['url']; ?>"><?php echo $second_level_link['title']; ?></a>`

It started happening after I upgraded the PHP on our site from 7.4 to 8.0

I have figure as much that the issue is revolving "$second_level_link" however I have two other link arrays set up the exact same way that don't get that error.

Here's the full code, I have bolded the sections where "second_level_link" get created:

```
$primary_menu_top_level = get_field('primary_menu_top_level', 'option');
if ($primary_menu_top_level) :
?>
<div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
        <?php
        **foreach($primary_menu_top_level as $item) :
            $top_level_link = $item['link'];
            $image = $item['image'];
            $description = $item['description'];
            $second_level = $item['second_level'];**
            ?>
            <li class="menu-item js-toggle-wrap">
                <a class="menu-item__top-level" href="<?php echo $top_level_link['url']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $top_level_link['title']; ?>
                    <?php 
                    if ($second_level) :
                    ?>
                        <span class="icon icon--dropdown js-toggle"></span>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    ?>
                </a>
                <?php
                if ($second_level) :
                ?>
                <ul class="sub-menu js-togglee">
                    <div class="container sub-menu__container">
                        <div class="sub-menu__image">
                            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, 'small_sqr'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sub-menu__text">
                            <div class="sub-menu__desc">
                                <?php echo $description; ?>
                            </div>
                            <a class="button" href="<?php echo $top_level_link['url']; ?>"><?php echo $top_level_link['title']; ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sub-menu__links">
                            <ul>
                            **<?php
                            foreach($second_level as $sub_item) :
                                $second_level_link = $sub_item['link'];
                                $third_level = $sub_item['third_level'];
                            ?>**
                            <li>
                                <a class="menu-item__second-level" href="<?php echo $second_level_link['url']; ?>"><?php echo $second_level_link['title']; ?></a>
                                <?php
                                if ($third_level) :
                                ?>
                                <ul>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($third_level as $third_item) :
                                        $third_level_link = $third_item['link'];
                                    ?>
                                    <li><a class="menu-item__third-level" href="<?php echo $third_level_link['url']; ?>"><?php echo $third_level_link['title']; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php
                                    endforeach;
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
                                <?php
                                endif;
                                ?>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php include( locate_template( 'template-parts/svg/wustl-shield.svg', false, false ) ); ?>
                </ul>
                <?php
                endif;
                ?>
            </li>
            <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: `$second_level_link` is a string, not an array, so you can't access `url` on it. I would suggest contacting the developers of the template to see if there's an update

Comment: i have added some more info to the original post - the code works perfectly with two other strings that are set up the same way as second_level_link. the issue seems to only happen with that one

Comment: Without dumping the variables, it's really hard to tell why `$second_level_link` is sometimes an array and sometimes a link. I'd suggest dumping or logging the variables to find out what they contain.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you *temporarily* modify the code right before the code above to include something like the following?

```
<?php echo gettype($second_level_link); ?>
```

Ideally, if you can do this in a copy of your app that's running on PHP 7.4, then repeat it on a copy that's running on 8.0, you should see a difference in the output.

(I'm assuming one will be an array and one will be a string. If you get an object for one of them, you can further explore using methods like get_class() and var_export().)

Then you'll need to figure out what's *in* the array and string, after which you can decide what you want to do. Any solution will probably involve making a change to whatever theme you're using (which I assume is called something like washu-ctl, albeit in a human-friendly form).

Before doing that, though, you'll probably want to verify that the theme authors haven't updated their template. They might have already saved you a bunch of trouble.